# Converting an ellipse into a circle (traffic sign)

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm doing a school project to detect and recognize traffic signs.
But sometimes because of the angle of the camera, the sign isn't circle shaped but more in the shape of an ellipse.

elliptic traffic sign resulting from my detection code
[image: elliptic traffic sign resulting from my detection code]

The thing is, I think it may later have an impact on the recognition part of the code that uses ai. But I have no idea if what I want to do is possible without dismorphing the numbers on the sign.
So is this kind of code possible?

Comment: Instead of converting an ellipse into a circle, it would be better to develop an AI that can recognize it even if it is in the shape of an ellipse. It is much easier that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @philipperoche "*...the recognition part of the code...*", to better answer your question, you might share a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the code you are using.

Comment: @ken Well I think my question is more: Do you think having elliptic signs will greatly impact an ai's performance in recognizing the sign? Like I can train an ai to also recognize ellipse signs, or is it more precise and fast to modify the pictures before making them go through the ai.

Comment: @Bilal Well I haven't really done any real code for the recognition part but it will be a regular image recognition AI like you would use to recognise handwritten numbers.

Comment: @philipperoche if [EasyOCRReader](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) can solve the recognition part, you might not need to do image reification.